# scala pattern matching dilemma

Tags: scala, design-patterns, pattern-matching

i have the following program which contains a recursive fucntion with pattern matching.
This code works

```
def randomSelect(num:Int, lst:List[Symbol]):List[Symbol] = (num, lst) match{

     /** traveerse list recursively extracting randomelemnents

    * 

    */

  case (n, l) =>  {

      if (n>0) {
        println("At " + n + " we got:" + l)
        val rnd = getRandom(l.length)
        val item = l(rnd)
        lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, l.filter(it => it != item))
      } else List[Symbol]()

  }

}
```

while the following does not. And i cannot understand why

```
def randomSelect(num:Int, lst:List[Symbol]):List[Symbol] = (num, lst) match{

     /** traveerse list recursively extracting randomelements

    * 

    */

  case (n, mylist) =>  {
         val rnd = getRandom(mylist.length)
         val item = mylist(rnd)
         lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, mylist.filter(it => it != item))

  }
  case (0, mylist) => List[Symbol]()
```

}

in the second conde snippet, case(0,mylist) is never invoked.

what am i missing?

kind regards
 marco

Comment: The first case will always match, move the second case before it.

Answer (score 2):

right now you have something like:

```
if (the input is a Tuple2) {
   do something
} else if (the input is a Tuple2 with a 0 as the first item) {
   do other thing
}
```

`case (n, mylist) =>` matches `(0, List(...))` you need to add a guard to the first expression or reorder your cases so that the 0 case is reached first.

so either:

```
case (0, mylist) => List[Symbol]()
case (n, mylist) =>  {
  val rnd = getRandom(mylist.length)
  val item = mylist(rnd)
  lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, mylist.filter(it => it != item))
}
```

or

```
case (n, mylist) if n > 0 =>  {
  val rnd = getRandom(mylist.length)
  val item = mylist(rnd)
  lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, mylist.filter(it => it != item))
}
case (0, mylist) => List[Symbol]()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following statement: `case (n, mylist)`, `n` is a variable that binds to any value in that position, which in your case is `num: Int`. So `n` is bound to all integer values. When it happens to be 0, your first case matches it and thus can never reach the second case statement.

There's two ways to solve this. First:

```
case (n, mylist) if n > 0 =>  {
         val rnd = getRandom(mylist.length)
         val item = mylist(rnd)
         lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, mylist.filter(it => it != item))

  }
case _ => List.empty[Symbol]
```

I used the wildcard since you don't use either the list or `n`.

Second way:

```
case (0, _) => List.empty[Symbol]
case (n, mylist) =>  {
         val rnd = getRandom(mylist.length)
         val item = mylist(rnd)
         lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, mylist.filter(it => it != item))

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned, reorder the cases so that the most specific is evaluated first.

Yet the pattern matching for two cases may be reduced to an `if-else` expression (not having to replicate an `if-else` via guards), noting that in this recursive method the base (trivial) case may be declared first, chiefly for enhancing readability,

```
def randomSelect(n:Int, l:List[Symbol]):List[Symbol] = {
  if (n <= 0) List[Symbol]()
  else {
      println("At " + n + " we got:" + l)
      val rnd = getRandom(l.length)
      val item = l(rnd)
      lst(rnd) :: randomSelect(n - 1, l.filter(it => it != item))
  }
}
```